# Add missing lines in file with python

Tags: python, file, lines, missing-data

I am a beginner when it comes to programming and python and such.
So apologies if this is kind of a simple question.

But I have large files that for example contain lines like this:

```
10000     7
20000     1
30000     2
60000     3
```

What I want to have, is a file that also contains the 'missing' lines, like this:

```
10000     7
20000     1
30000     2
40000     0
50000     0
60000     3
```

The files are rather large as I am working with whole genome sequence data. The first column is basically a position in the genome and the second column is the number of SNPs I find within that 10kb window. However, I don't think this information is even relevant, I just want to write a simple python code that will add these lines to the file by using if else statements.

So if the position does not match the position of the previous line + 10000, the 'missing line' is written, otherwise the normal occurring line is written.

I just foresee one problem in this, namely when several lines in a row are missing (as in my example). 
Does anyone have a smart solution for this simple problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: For that you have to write code. It is simple. Try by your own. For any particular issue that you will face during the process; you may always come back here. For now it is off-topic for SO

Comment: Read the first file into a dictionary, then add the missing numbers to that dictionary, then write that dictionary to a file

Comment: "So if the position does not match the position of the previous line + 10000, the 'missing line' is written, otherwise the normal occurring line is written." You've made the harder, find what to do.

Comment: Thanks, and I am aware that I can try harder to come up with my own simple code but the first lines are for me as a beginner also the hardest... And I don't believe that this kind of question is off-topic, because there are a lot of people like me out there that have trouble when they are in their beginning phase of coding. Sorry if my question is very simple and maybe even dumb but I am also trying behind the scenes. Thanks for the quick responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
# Replace lines.txt with your actual file
with open("lines.txt", "r") as file:
    last_line = 0
    lines = []
    for line in file:
        num1, num2 = [int(i) for i in line.split("\t")]
        while num1 != last_line + 10000:
            # A line is missing
            lines.append((last_line + 10000, 0)) 
            last_line += 10000
        lines.append((num1, num2))
        last_line = num1
    for num1, num2 in lines:
        # You should print to a different file here
        print(num1, num2)
```

Instead of the last print statement you would write the values to a new file.

**Edit:** I ran this code on this sample. Output below.

**lines.txt**

```
10000   7
20000   1
30000   2
60000   3
```

**Output**

```
10000 7
20000 1
30000 2
40000 0
50000 0
60000 3
```

Comment: I have tried this so far, it is almost working but now for the lines that are already there I get a copied line with 0, like this:

10000 7
10000 0
20000 1
20000 0
30000 2
30000 0
40000 0
50000 0
60000 3

Is there an obvious flaw that I am missing int he above code? It is very understandable by the way so thanks a lot :)!

Comment: I'm happy to help. I ran the code again and edited my answer to show the result. From what I understand this is what you asked for. **Please make sure you're not writing the changed data to the original file and that the two numbers are actually seperated by a tab.**

Comment: Hi, No I wasn't thanks! I forgot to set the last_lines to num1 (or add 10000) outside of the while loop, which is why I got the output with num2 = 0 for every line in the file (because the while statement was never met). So thanks again, it works now, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a program along the following lines. You keep track of the genome position you saw last (it would be 0 at the start, I guess). Then you read lines from the input file, one by one. For each one, you output first any missing lines (from the previous genome position + 10kb, in 10kb steps, to 10kb before the new line you've read) and then the line you have just read.

In other words, the tiny thing you're missing is that when "the position does not match the position of the previous line + 10000", you should have a little loop to generate the missing output, rather than just writing out one line. (The following remark may make no sense until you actually start writing the code: You don't actually need to test whether the position matches; if you write it right, you will find that when it matches your loop outputs no extra lines)

For various good reasons, the usual practice here is not to write the code for you :-), but I hope the above will help.

Comment: Thanks for the quick nice response!

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
with open('file1.txt') as infile:
    for l in infile:
        pos, count = l.split()
        d[int(pos)] = int(count)

with open('file2.txt') as outfile:
    for i in range(10000, pos+1, 10000):
        outfile.write('{}\t{}'.format(i, d[i]))
```

Here's a quick version.  We read the file into a `defaultdict`.  When we access the values later, any key that doesn't have an associated value will get the default value of zero.  Then we take every number in the range `10000` to `pos` where `pos` is the last position in the first file, taken in steps of `10000`.  We access these values in the `defaultdict` and write them to the second file.

Comment: Thanks! I know I could use a dictionary, but does this not use a lot of memory?

Comment: @visse226 How big are your files?  Dictionaries don't generally take up that much space. Unless you expect inputs with millions of lines, you're probably fine.

Comment: I have files with approximately 200k lines each so I think it could work. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `defaultdict` which will use `0` as default value
So you will read your file to this `defaultdict` and than read it (handling keys manually) and write it back to file.

It will look somewhat like this

```
from collections import defaultdict

x = defaultdict(int)
with open(filename) as f:
    data = x.split()
    x[data[0]] = x[data[-1]]

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for i in range(0, max(x.keys())+1, 10000):
        f.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(i, x[i]))
```